# Does purity mean here that "deny" is a "quality of being morally good"?

Tags: meaning

This comic says

> there is a purity in that

[image]

what does purity mean here?

cambridge gives this definition "the quality of being morally good"

why is "deny" a "quality of being morally good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Purity" can also mean *simplicity*. Something in its purest form is free from any contamination, or impurities.

Looking at the previous panel in the comic, it refers to a "lust for vengeance". This is a very *base* emotion. I believe the implication is that while vengeance is a negative emotion, it is basic, uncomplicated, and that is the meaning of "pure" in this context.

The words are evidently being spoken by one character to another. One is suggesting that the other is "denying" himself the purity vengeance by his refraining from it. Evidently one of the characters has a much greater moral integrity than the other.

Comment: so, in this context, vengeance is some kind of simplicity, right?

Comment: I guess I got it. Thank you so much! Btw, which one is the bad guy? Ironhide?

Comment: @brennn Oh, well maybe it isn't a bad guy then - Ironhide is an Autobot as well. According to Wikipedia, Optimus Prime " is constantly, if not always depicted as having strong moral character", so rather than bad guy to good guy, this is apparently more sincere - Ironhide is being contrasted to Optimus, who has a greater strength of character not to give in to vengeance.

Comment: In the right hand pane, the person speaking in the upper text box says that 'there's a purity in that', and the lower text box says 'one that you've always tried to deny'. I would interpret that as 'a purity whose existence you've always tried to deny'.